# phpmyadmin connecting to a remote server

Tags: mysql, lamp

I have two servers (ubuntu 10.04 amd 64). one i plan on the webserver, the other i plan on being the database server. The webserver is the only server with access to the outside world. I installed a LAMP stack with phpmyadmin. On the database server, in mysql i created a user with the host of the internal ip address of the webserver. On the webserver I edited the config-db.php file to point the variable $dbserver to the internal ip address of the database server. When I go to the phpmyadmin page to login i should expect to login using the newly created user. I can't for the life of me get this setup to work.

Comment: What, exactly, is not working?  What error messages are you receiving?  What behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/FZ6nqD

Answer (score 6):

Are you setting up your phpmyadmin config correctly with the server's information you want to conect to?
see the phpmyadmin wiki page: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#Server.28s.29_configuration

It should be as simple as just typing in the SQL server's IP/domain.

Additionally you can specify a username and password in the config. But if the phpmyadmin webpage is accessible externally this would be a very bad idea as anyone who got to that page would have assess to your sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider editing `config.inc.php` instead of `config-db.php` (like here: http://www.mittalpatel.co.in/access_mysql_database_hosted_remote_server_using_phpmyadmin)

In `config.inc.php`, there is your base host defined. You may add another one afterwards by inserting something like this:

```
<?php

// The $i counter should already be incremented, if not, uncomment the next line
// $i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '';        // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';        // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';     // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';  // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';  // Authentication method (valid choices: config, http, signon or cookie)

// 0 enables choosing host via a dropdown menu
// 1 sets the first one as default
// 2 sets the second one as default
// etc.
$cfg['ServerDefault']                = 0;
?>
```

Comment: I don't feel like having enough expertise in this configuration to make definitive statements, but if that's preferred, I expand my answear with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below lines to your “config.inc.php” file in the bottom:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'HostName:port'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'userName';   //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';       // keep it as config
```

. You will get  “Current Server:” drop down  with both “127.0.0.1” and one what you have provided with “$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']” cam switch between the servers.

Comment: Please do not post shortened links.